# How to change the way in which the root controller of a navigation controller is appearing on screen?

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

The navigation controller is not the initial view controller. It is being instantiated in the initial VC and supplied with a root controller, the second VC. When I call present view controller function I cannot change the way in which this new VC in being presented, it always appears from the bottom. I did not find how to make it come from right to left. I tried to change who gets the call to modalPresentaionStyle from the second VC to the nav con and back but no change.
Code listing below. Thank you for your help.

```
@objc fileprivate func showRegisterScreen() { 
    let registerAccountVC = RegisterAccountVC()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: registerAccountVC)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a custom animation from right to left.

```
let transition = CATransition.init()
transition.duration = 0.4
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```